# Android Post Request Error using HttpURLConnection

Tags: android, http, post

I am trying to do a post request in Android. This is the code I am using but it cause the app to crash

```
    String urlParameters = "user="+ email.getText().toString() + "&name="+ Username.getText().toString() + "&pass="+ pass.getText().toString() +"";

    // Send post request
    URL serverUrl =
            new URL("http://schoolcheating.3eeweb.com/new_user.php");
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) serverUrl.openConnection();

    // Indicate that we want to write to the HTTP request body
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

    // Writing the post data to the HTTP request body
    BufferedWriter httpRequestBodyWriter =
            new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream()));
    httpRequestBodyWriter.write(urlParameters);
    httpRequestBodyWriter.close();
```

The crash happens at the defining off "httpRequestBodyWriter". Here is the error log:

```
10-24 19:48:04.049  10501-10501/com.example.mohamedsherif.mysql E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.mohamedsherif.mysql, PID: 10501
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4221)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5155)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20747)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4216)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5155)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20747)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
     Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
            at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1147)
            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
            at com.android.okhttp.HostResolver$1.getAllByName(HostResolver.java:29)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:232)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:124)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:361)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:289)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:373)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:106)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:208)
            at com.example.mohamedsherif.mysql.MainActivity.llll(MainActivity.java:73)
            at com.example.mohamedsherif.mysql.MainActivity.cr(MainActivity.java:57)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4216)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5155)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20747)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

also this is the php code of the file that i send to it the post request

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will create a new product row
 * All product details are read from HTTP Post Request
*/

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
$user = $_POST['user']; //User Name
$pass = $_POST['pass']; //Password
$name = $_POST['name']; //Name
$school = $_POST['school']; //School
$type = $_POST['type']; //Type
$pic = $_POST['pic']; //Profile Picture


// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// mysql inserting a new row
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO user(username, name, school, type, profile_picture, password) VALUES('$user', '$name', '$school', '$type', '$pic', '$pass')");

// check if row inserted or not
if ($result) {
    // successfully inserted into database
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "User successfully created.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // failed to insert row
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
} else {
// required field is missing
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Comment: please share error log

Comment: Dude, NullPointer in your urlConnection. Check if urlConnection gets HTTP_OK or not

Comment: how to check it @AnkurAggarwal

Comment: i added the error log now @ρяσѕρєяK

Comment: @MohamedSherif: [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Comment: You have **extremely serious security issues** with this PHP code (SQL injection and unhashed/unsalted passwords). You will put your users' security, and your system, at risk if you use it. Switch to a database library that is still currently maintained, use parameter binding for your queries, and an appropriate hashing/salting algorithm for your password storage.

Comment: Yes i know @halfer this is only for testing of course before publishing i will close sql injections and xss and csrf but this is only for testing Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your Error logs you are getting **NetworkOnMainThreadException** ,this is because you are performing network operations on  main thread i.e UI thread .You need to perform this operation inside a background thread like **AsyncTask** .Put your network connection code inside doInBackground() of AsyncTask .

```
private class BackgroundOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
        //Your network connection code should be here .
        String response = postCall();
        return response ;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //Print your response here .
        Log.d("Post Response",result);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {}

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
}

    public String  postCall(){
    URL url;
    HashMap<String ,String> postDataParams = new HashMap<String ,String>();
        postDataParams .put("user", email.getText().toString());
        postDataParams .put("name", Username.getText().toString());
        postDataParams .put("pass", pass.getText().toString());

    String response = "";
    try {
        url = new URL(""http://schoolcheating.3eeweb.com/new_user.php"");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();
        int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();
        if(responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
            String line;
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {response+=line;}}else {
            response="";    }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();}
    return response;
}

 private String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;
        for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()){
            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                result.append("&");

            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
            result.append("=");
            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
        }

        return result.toString();
    }
```

Now you can call above from from your activity's onCreate() function using below code .

```
new BackgroundOperation().execute("");
```

Note : Don't forget to mention below permission in your manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: it doesn't crash now but nothing is added to the server

Comment: The problem you have mentioned here ,has been solved ,now should upvote and accept the answer .

Comment: You should ask another question with the problem you are facing now .

Comment: Of course no cause it is the same problem and i am sure that my php code is working cause i tested it so the problem has to be in the http connection done from android and that means you didnt solve my question

Comment: I have edited the above answer to meet your requirement , It's working code for me . I have printed the response in Logcat ,so check your Logcat after executing above code .

Comment: Thanks i am going test when i go back home and tell you but it looks like it works @Android Dev

Comment: I am getting {"success":1,"message":"User successfully created."}
in my Logcat . So it should work for you definitely .

Comment: Really Thanks you have solved a problem that i faced for about a year